# More than one firewall at Symfony2 project security.yml, how to deal with pattern?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle, symfony-2.6

I am working in a project where I will need two firewalls or secured areas. The first firewall/secured area will allow login/logout using [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) using Salesforce as provider, the second firewall/secured area will allow login/logout through [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) since this is for internal sysadmin and so on. I have a doubt trying to get `security.yml` file well setup since I don't know how to deal with `pattern` parameter. I have read [Security reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) but have not idea in how to do this. This is what I have at the moment:

```
firewalls:
        #this is the public area accessed by/from iOs app and only users registered at Salesforce as rep can login
        rep_area:
            methods: [GET, POST]
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            logout: true

        #this is the secured area accessed through web browser and only internals are allowed to login
        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous:    ~
```

How should I configure `pattern` in that case?

**Update: firewalls not working**

This is how the firewalls section looks after users answer:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    #this is the secured area accessed through web browser and only internals are allowed to login
    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        anonymous:    ~
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            post_only: true
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            target_path_parameter: _target_path
            use_referer: false
            failure_path: null
            failure_forward: false
        logout:
            path:   fos_user_security_logout
            target: /

    #this is the public area accessed by/from iOs app and only users registered at Salesforce as rep can login
    rep_area:
        methods: [GET, POST]
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        logout: true
```

But if I try `http://appdev.local/app_dev.php/admin/` I got this error:

> InvalidConfigurationException in BaseNode.php line 313: Invalid
>   configuration for path "security.firewalls.admin_area": The check_path
>   "/login_check" for login method "form_login" is not matched by the
>   firewall pattern "^/admin".

Why?

**Edit 2: what about if have FOSUserBundle && HWIOAuth work together?**

As additional info and I forgot to tell this from the very beginning, I have and need FOSUserBundle && HWIOAuth installed and I am trying to get both working as should be. In that case this is how my `routing.yml`  looks like:

```
#HWIOAuthBundle
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

hwi_oauth_login:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix:   /login

salesforce_login:
    pattern: /login/check-salesforce

#PDOne
pd_one:
    resource: "@PDOneBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

template:
    resource: "@TemplateBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

#FOSUserBundle
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
fos_user_security:
    prefix: /admin
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

#SonataAdmin
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

How I should deal with prefix between FOSUserBundle && HWIOAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply

```
firewalls:
    #this is the secured area accessed through web browser and only internals are allowed to login
            admin_area:
                pattern:    ^/admin
                anonymous:    ~

        #this is the public area accessed by/from iOs app and only users registered at Salesforce as rep can login
        rep_area:
            methods: [GET, POST]
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            logout: true
```

It's a regex telling symfony that all routes `^` (beginning) with `/` follow this rule.  Or `/admin` follow another rule.  The firewall will always follow whatever rule it matches first.  So your admin rule must come first or else it won't work.

**Edit**

In your routes settings where you add in the security routes for FOS UserBundle try having /admin appended as a prefix.  Could be because /admin is your rule but the route being generated for login is `host.com/login` instead of `host.com/admin/login`

```
fos_user_security:
    prefix: /admin
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

Comment: Almost there, can you re-check my post? I am having some issues trying those working together and need some help, btw, thanks for take some time and try to help

Comment: It may be because you're including "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml" which already includes the security part.  So if you're using all of UserBundle just for the admin panel, move the prefix: /admin to fos_user and get rid of fos_user_security all together.

Comment: Thx, can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990520/fosuserbundle-hwioauth-security-configuration-failed) post and give me a clue if you know what is wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to use FOSUserBundle in areas of the site other than /admin ?

Comment: No, will be only for /admin

Comment: Yep, I tried and didn't work I think is because the issue I'm having the one in the other post I linked to you here

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look I may be missing something too but I know this works.  I'm actually building a system right now that has an admin panel with FOSUserBundle then uses another custom system for authing API calls.  I'll respond on your new question.